# Lag unbalanced panel dataset in Matlab

Tags: matlab, panel-data

I have an unbalanced panel dataset in Matlab that I need to lag. Unbalanced panel datasets are quite easu to work with in R with the `plm` package. Is there a similar functionality in Matlab? Here is a toy example:

```
A = table(sort([repmat([1;2],4,1);repmat(3,3,1)]),[repmat((1994:1997).',2,1);(1995:1997).'],normrnd(100,1,11,1))

A = 

    Var1    Var2     Var3 
    ____    ____    ______

    1       1994    98.423
    1       1995    100.51
    1       1996    100.28
    1       1997    100.03
    2       1994    98.666
    2       1995    101.13
    2       1996    100.35
    2       1997    99.701
    3       1995    100.02
    3       1996    99.738
    3       1997     98.25
```

For each instance of Var1, I would like to lag the value of Var3 one year. Note that there is no value for 1994 for Var1=3. Thus, I would like the following:

```
    Var1    Var2     Var3      Var4 
    ____    ____    ______    ______

    1       1994    98.423       NaN
    1       1995    100.51    98.423
    1       1996    100.28    100.51
    1       1997    100.03    100.28
    2       1994    98.666       NaN
    2       1995    101.13    98.666
    2       1996    100.35    101.13
    2       1997    99.701    100.35
    3       1995    100.02       NaN
    3       1996    99.738    100.02
    3       1997     98.25    99.738
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself using `varfun`:

```
A = table(sort([repmat([1;2],4,1);repmat(3,3,1)]),[repmat((1994:1997).',2,1);(1995:1997).'],normrnd(100,1,11,1))

B = varfun(@(x)lagmatrix(x,1),A,'GroupingVariables','Var1')
```